# Plasma Linear Tearing Mode Theory Fitzpatrick

Tags: plasma-physics

I've been looking through Richard Fitzpatrick's book on plasma physics on the section on linear tearing mode theory (shown below) and there are a few equations I haven't been able to replicate, except using strange assumptions. Specifically, equations 7.173 and by extension 7.186. The description of 7.185 as the flux-freezing constraint only checks out with the same assumption.

According to the book, 7.186 is the linearised form of $\nabla \times (\boldsymbol{j} \times \boldsymbol{B}) = 0$ or

$$\nabla \times [(\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_0) \times \boldsymbol{B}_1 + (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_1) \times \boldsymbol{B}_0] =0$$
ignoring displacement current. From my understanding $\boldsymbol{B}_1 = B_x(x)\text{exp}(iky + \gamma t)\hat{\boldsymbol{i}} $ and $\boldsymbol{B}_0 = B_{0y}(x)\hat{\boldsymbol{j}}$.
With this I obtain
$$(\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_0) \times \boldsymbol{B}_1 = B_{0y}'B_x\hat{\boldsymbol{j}}$$
and
$$ (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_1) \times \boldsymbol{B}_0 = ikB_xB_{0y}\hat{\boldsymbol{i}}$$
which combines to
$$
\nabla \times [(\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_0) \times \boldsymbol{B}_1 + (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_1) \times \boldsymbol{B}_0] = k^2 B_x B_{0y} + B_{0y}''B_x + B_x'B_{0y}' =0 
$$
which does not agree. If you instead assume an extra perturbed component $B_{1y} = B_{0y}\text{exp}(iky + \gamma t)$ then the Maxwell equation $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{B} = 0 $ becomes
$$
ikB_{0y} + B_x' = 0.
$$
Redoing the previous calculations with the extra perturbed component
$$
\nabla \times [(\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_0) \times \boldsymbol{B}_1 + (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B}_1) \times \boldsymbol{B}_0] = k^2 B_x B_{0y} + B_{0y}''B_x + B_x'B_{0y}' - 2 B_{0y}'B_{0y}ik=0 
$$
which can be combined with Maxwell's equation to give the correct answer.

The flux freezing condition too works with this. Assuming a surface normal to the $x$ direction of area $A$ the flux is $B_xA$ and the flux equation is
$$
\frac{\partial B_x }{\partial t}A + V_x \frac{\partial B_x}{\partial x} A  = 
\gamma B_x A + V_x B_x' A =0
$$
which, combined with Maxwell's equation again gives
$$\gamma B_x = ik V_x B_{0y}.$$

But this extra perturbation doesn't really make sense to me. I'm not sure why the unperturbed function should be used with the exponential variation. However, Maxwell's equation without it would imply $B_x'=0$ which is not interesting.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]